# How to combine distinct records of multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

I'm using SQL in Azure databricks. My databricks version is 10.4 LTS  (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12).

I have a table with 5 columns of mail id & mail id's are repeating in some columns for same row.

My sample table looks like this:

```
|    Mail_1    |    Mail_2    |    Mail_3    |    Mail_4    |    Mail_5    |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|a.gmail.com   | a.aol.com    | a1.gmail.com | a.gmail.com  | a1.gmail.com |
|b.gmail.com   | b.aol.com    | b1.gmail.com | b.yahoo.com  | null         |
```

I need to combine these columns as  & create a column Mail with unique record.

My additional output column will look like:

```
|                              Mail                               
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|a.gmail.com,a.aol.com,a1.gmail.com                               |
|b.gmail.com,b.aol.com,b1.gmail.com,b.yahoo.com                   |
```

My `mail_1` to `mail_5` columns might have null value.

Can you please suggest how to do this?

Comment: I think `array_distinct` would work here. My cluster is warming up to confirm. My cluster is taking forever to start. But I think it's simply `select array_distinct(array(mail_1, mail_2, mail_3, mail_4, mail_5)) as mail from table_name`.

Comment: Not sure the syntax in Databricks, but in SQL Server you can use some cobination of `CROSS APPLY`, `STRING_AGG`, `DISTINCT` and a `VALUES` constructor to get what you want https://dbfiddle.uk/Dhd8nFJ2 I think Databricks uses `LATERAL VIEW` or some such, and `array_join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wanting to remove null, you can use `array_except`. If you don't want the output to look like an array, then you could use `concat_ws` combined with `array_distinct`.

```
with my_data as (
  select 1 as id, 'a.gmail.com' as Mail_1, 'a.aol.com' as Mail_2, 'a1.gmail.com' as Mail_3, 'a.gmail.com' as Mail_4, 'a1.gmail.com' as Mail_5 union all
  select 2, 'b.gmail.com', 'b.aol.com', 'b1.gmail.com', 'b.yahoo.com', null
 )
select 
  id, 
  array_except(array(mail_1, mail_2, mail_3, mail_4, mail_5), array(null)) as mail, 
  concat_ws(',', array_distinct(array(mail_1, mail_2, mail_3, mail_4, mail_5)), NULL) as mailed
from my_data
order by id
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  mail                                                             mailed
1   ["a.gmail.com", "a.aol.com", "a1.gmail.com"]                     a.gmail.com,a.aol.com,a1.gmail.com
2   ["b.gmail.com", "b.aol.com", "b1.gmail.com", "b.yahoo.com"]      b.gmail.com,b.aol.com,b1.gmail.com,b.yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You only require the array function to access all columns and concat_ws to concatenate columns separated by commas. like below.

SQL

```
SELECT
  CONCAT_WS(",", ARRAY (*)) AS Mail
FROM
VALUES 
    ("a.gmail.com", "a.aol.com", "a1.gmail.com", "a.gmail.com", "a1.gmail.com"),
    ("b.gmail.com", "b.aol.com", "b1.gmail.com", "b.yahoo.com", NULL) 
AS (Mail_1, Mail_2, Mail_3, Mail_4, Mail_5)
```

DataFrame

```
df.select(concat_ws(",",array($"*")))
```

Output

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|Mail                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|a.gmail.com,a.aol.com,a1.gmail.com,a.gmail.com,a1.gmail.com|
|b.gmail.com,b.aol.com,b1.gmail.com,b.yahoo.com             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```